# how do I copy files from a remote host to my computer?

Tags: unix, ssh, shell, scp

I am trying to use the following command:

```
$ scp remoteusername@host:$HOME/fileiwanttocopy /my/local/comp
```

I woould like for home to be evaluated on the remote host instead of my computer (which it is doing now) i've tried it with and without quotes.

Answer (score 5):

To copy a file from the home directory on another machine, use:

```
scp remoteusername@host:fileiwanttocopy /my/local/comp
```

Note that the filename after ':' does *not* start with a '/', so it is relative from the home directory by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to copy a file from your home directory you could use either of the following:

```
$ scp remoteusername@host:fileiwanttocopy /my/local/comp
$ scp remoteusername@host:~/fileiwanttocopy /my/local/comp
```

The `~` will evaluate to the logged in user's home directory.
If you woul like to copy a file from another user's home directory you would use::

```
$ scp remoteusername@host:~anotheruser/fileiwanttocopy /my/local/comp
```

In which `~anotheruser` would resolve to the user "anotheruser"'s home directory.